# thrift or pyro is better if I want to make a RPC service use python? is there a better choice besides them?

Tags: python, rpc, thrift, pyro

I will make a RPC service about suggest, server calculate the suggest data,client for request to server.This system will be written with python,What is the good choice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this python - to - python communication I like [RPYC](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which includes good features for limiting remote access while staying pythonic.

You should [take a look at this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410328/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-pyro-and-rpyc-python-libs)